# Starting expressjs api with custom-env

Tags: node.js, express

I want to start my project using different environments and I am trying to do that using custom-env.
I have added this to my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "SET NODE_ENV=staging && node app.js"
  },
```

But running this makes my environment become "staging " with a space. So the right environment file won't be picked up. How can I set NODE_ENV to staging and run the app at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try

```
try "start": "SET NODE_ENV=staging&& node app.js"
```